# Elasticsearch 2.3 Geo Shape type mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial, quadtree

I have a field in Elasticsearch index with the following mapping

```
   "cluster_boundary": {
        "type": "geo_shape",
        "tree": "quadtree",
        "precision": "1mm"
    }
```

but when I put this mapping in The elasticsearch index I get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: maxLevels of 36 exceeds limit of 29
     at org.apache.lucene.spatial.prefix.tree.PackedQuadPrefixTree.<init>(PackedQuadPrefixTree.java:70)
     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.GeoShapeFieldMapper$GeoShapeFieldType.freeze(GeoShapeFieldMapper.java:276)
     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.<init>(FieldMapper.java:289)
     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.GeoShapeFieldMapper.<init>(GeoShapeFieldMapper.java:428)
     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.GeoShapeFieldMapper$Builder.build(GeoShapeFieldMapper.java:160)
     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.GeoShapeFieldMapper$Builder.build(GeoShapeFieldMapper.java:119)
     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$Builder.build(ObjectMapper.java:167)
     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper$Builder.<init>(DocumentMapper.java:88)
     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperBuilders.doc(MapperBuilders.java:44)
     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:118)
     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:99)
     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:498)
     at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.applyRequest(MetaDataMappingService.java:257)
     at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:230)
     at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService.runTasksForExecutor(InternalClusterService.java:468)
     at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:772)
     at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:231)
     at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:194)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I change the `quadtree` to `geohash` it works.And, as per elasticsearch the maximum allowed tree levels in `quadtree` is `50`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum level possible for `PackedQuadPrefixTree` is 29 while for `QuadPrefixTree` is 50. You can check that [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/spatial-extras/constant-values.html#org.apache.lucene.spatial.prefix.tree.QuadPrefixTree.DEFAULT_MAX_LEVELS) and [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/spatial-extras/org/apache/lucene/spatial/prefix/tree/PackedQuadPrefixTree.html).

I looked through the ES [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/3f77eacab14e70da2d7ee4720f55552f4f4242d9/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/mapper/GeoShapeFieldMapper.java#L267). `quadtree` maps to lucene `PackedQuadPrefixTree`  so you would have to lower the precision value to `1m` which translates to 26 tree_levels OR you could use `legacyquadtree` which has max 50 levels.

The one thing I noticed is ES throws `out of memory error` if you specify very high number of levels with `legacyquadtree` rather than saying maximum allowed level is 50.

```
PUT test_index/_mapping/test_type
{
  "properties": {
    "test": {
      "type": "geo_shape",
      "tree": "legacyquadtree",
      "tree_levels": "54354552"
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally above code should say max level is 50 but it runs out of heap space and throws OOM error.

I also think that 1mm is too precise and even with leagcyquadtree it will take lot of memory. [More](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/geo-shape.html#_performance_considerations) on that. I have also opened an [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21191) on github which you could follow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As per the elasticsearch documentation ```quadtree``` has a maximum 50 levels. Based on what you say the documentation seems to be wrong. I will try using ```legacyquadtree```. I have tried ```1m```  precision and the tree level is ```33``` .